# Fixed distance buffer is oval in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, vector, buffer, circle

I want to create circles of diameter 20m in QGIS. I create a point and then use vector - geoprocessing tools - fixed distance buffer. My problem is that the size is crazy and worse, the shape is not a circle. My map units are metres and when I use a distance of 0.001 I get an oval 220 m high in north-south direction and 140 m wide in east-west direction.

I am using OSGB 1936 / British National Grid EPSG:27700. I have tried switching to another reference system and back again since in other cases this seems to make QGIS pay attention, but it has not helped in this case.

Comment: QGIS doesn't care which CRS your project has, it cares about the layer's CRS. Which currently seems to be some geographic CRS. So save your layer in a different, projected CRS, then buffer.

Comment: 0.001 degrees of longitude varies from ~111m near the Equator to ~0m near the poles. A geodetic buffer takes this into account, generating visibly egg-shaped objects in high latitudes.

Comment: Erik - thats it. Making sure the layer with the points in uses British National Grid solves the problem. Thanks very much.    Steve